# $\text{deg}\ a(x)b(x) <\text{ deg}\ a(x)+ \text{deg}\ b(x).$

Tags: abstract-algebra

> If A is an integral domain, we have seen that in $A[x]$, $\text{deg }a(x)b(x)=\text{deg }a(x)+\text{deg }b(x)$. Show that if $A$ is not an integral doamin we can find polynomails $a(x), b(x)$ such that $$\text{deg}\ a(x)b(x) <\text{ deg}\ a(x)+ \text{deg}\ b(x).$$

So if we don't have an integral domain then we can use zero divisors. You can multiply by one of the zero divisors and a nonzero element and then deg $a(x)b(x)$ would be zero and $\text{deg}\ a(x)+\text{deg }b(x)$ would be some element greater than zero. If this a good explanation? Is there a way to formulate a more detailed and mathematical proof?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $r,s\in A$ be non-zero such that $rs=0$, and consider, say, $a(x)=rx^3$ and $b(x)=sx^7+1$.

Comment: So I get $a(x)b(x)=rx^3\cdot sx^7+1=rsx^{10}+rx^3$ and $rs=0$ so $a(x)b(x)=rx^3$. For $a(x)+b(x)=rx^3+sx^7+1$ which clearly has a larger degree. Is this correct?

Comment: What does $a(x) + b(x)$ have to do with anything? $\deg a(x) = 3, \deg b(x) = 7$ and $\deg a(x)b(x) = 3 \lneq 3+7 = \deg a(x) + \deg b(x)$.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, that's the idea. Suppose that $a \in A$ is a zero divisor, so that $ab = 0$ for some $b \neq 0$. Consider the constant polynomial $a(x) = a$ and the linear polynomial $b(x) = bx$. Then $$\deg a(x)b(x) = \deg abx = \deg 0 = -\infty < 1 = 0 + 1 = \deg a + \deg bx = \deg a(x) + \deg b(x)$$